# How to get general data from facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm looking into the facebook graph api. I understand that I can retrieve information about a facebook web page by making a get with the current id. It's also clear that after retrieving a access token I can post on the logged in users wall and do other operations.

But what if I want more general data? Can I, for example, get how many swedish user who have used the word "Obama" in their status update the last week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the current `search` API can be that specific. You can find everything about the search API in this [document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/).